# How can I decode calls to the songbird network?

Tags: contract-invocation, multisignature, calldata, decoding, wrapped-tokens

for example: I am a multisig signer. And I want to decode the call data that is used to call  a specific smart contract.

example on smart contract : 0x02f0826ef6aD107Cfc861152B32B52fD11BaB9ED (WNat)
I want to decode this call data: 0x2e1a7d4d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001158e460913d00000

Is there a way to decode this call in order to see the transaction details.

another example: if I want to decode a pre signed transaction. to make sure it has the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

To decode calls on Songbird network you can use this tool: https://decoder.aflabs.si/.

It uses the [songbird explorer](https://songbird-explorer.flare.network/) to get contract ABI from the contract's address and then decodes the function call and its parameters. In your example it works as expected:

[image: Decoded contract call]

Comment: Thanks
very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the previous answer to help people understand how to interpret the encoding.

The call data is composed of 2 parts :

1. Function selector (4 first bytes)
2. Parameters (everything after the 4 first bytes)

The function selector is the 4 first bytes of the keccack-256 of the function signature hash:

The function: `withdraw(uint256 _amount)` signature is `withdraw(uint256)`:

keccack256 of `withdraw(uint256)` is :

```
2e1a7d4d13322e7b96f9a57413e1525c250fb7a9021cf91d1540d5b69f16a49f
```

The first 4 bytes are : `2e1a7d4d` matching the first 4 bytes of your calldata.

Next, we know from the signature that this function accepts one parameter of type uint256 (so 32 bytes).

This parameter is encoded in the call data as : `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001158e460913d00000`

converting this Hex representation to decimals we get :

```
20000000000000000000
```

So we can conclude that the calldata targetted the withdraw function with an amount of `20000000000000000000` as parameter.